# Print text after Download file in ASP Webform C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to print the status of training method in the webpage. and also downloading the log file. Here is my code:

```
 string fileout = "AddLabelLog_" + dates + ".log";
    string fileoutput = Server.MapPath("~/TrainLog/") + fileout;

    System.Web.HttpResponse response1 = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
    response1.ClearContent();
    response1.Clear();
    response1.ContentType = "text/html";
    response1.AddHeader("Content-Disposition",
                       "attachment; filename=" + fileout);
    response1.TransmitFile(fileoutput);
    response1.Flush();
    response1.End();

    var strLines = File.ReadLines(fileoutput);
    foreach (var line in strLines)
    {
        if (line.Contains("FAILED"))
        {
            Result1.Text = "Your Training Is Failed. Please Check The Log.";
            break;


        }
        else
        {
            Result1.Text = "Your System Has been Trained";

        }
    }
```

I found the problem was because of this code:

```
System.Web.HttpResponse response1 = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
response1.ClearContent();
response1.Clear();
response1.ContentType = "text/html";
response1.AddHeader("Content-Disposition",
                   "attachment; filename=" + fileout);
response1.TransmitFile(fileoutput);
response1.Flush();
response1.End();
```

It can't print Result1.Text if I put the code for downloading file. What should I do to be able to print the message in Result1.Text and also downloading the file?

Comment: Use Ajax. You cannot update the UI and download a file at the same time.

Comment: `var strLines = File.ReadLines(fileoutput);` => this is not a proper way. You need to store the file first, then use `ReadLines` from stored file to assign it into `Text` property then return response from that.

Comment: you cannot send a file for download and also send page content back to the browser within a single HTTP request. You can only return one thing at a time.